# Ignore validation while saving / destroying document with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, validation, mongoid

I have a problem with mongoid. I have validation on some field, called `flickr_id`. The problem is, that Mongo doesn't support transactions and sometimes, somehow, despite the fact that there is `validates :flickr_id, :uniqueness => true`, there are duplicates in a database. How can I remove them from Rails application? Because anytime I want to do something with these objects which aren't unique, I get an error that it's not valid. How can I ignore validation in such situation?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `validates_uniqueness_of` an works as expected. Assuming that what you want is to clean your DB, you can comment that line and remove duplicated documents through console.

If not the case, you can add `on` to your validation, so the validation is only run when creating/updating but not when destroying:

> :on Only run when specified, supports :create and :update.

More info [here](http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/validation.html).

Comment: ":on Only run when specified, supports :create and :update." - does it mean it doesn't support destroy?

Answer (score 1):

Try `object.delete` instead of `object.destroy`.